# Editing the style of a JavaScript rendered page element once loaded on my page using Async/Await

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to edit the style of a page element which is rendered by a third party script.
I know I can target the elements using

`const variable = document.querySelector('.class')`

and then change the style using

`variable.style.colorEtc = 'red or whatever';`

I previously tried to just use

`setTimeout(changeStyle, delay)`

but the load time is unpredictable and can cause issues.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use promises and async/await to cause the query selectors and style changes to load asynchronously and then run once the targets are rendered.

I have no idea what this looks like in practice. How can I target a js render performed by third party script as the condition that the variables are awaiting to run once loaded?

I hope I understood async/await correctly, but if not, I'm open to alternative solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post more code of what you have tried/ are trying to do?

Comment: Hello! Yeah, I'm trying to make css changes to my termly cookie banner to reduce the size on mobile by reducing padding and perhaps button sizes. There is a small collection of style edits available from termly and I really only want to make a few small additional tweaks.

Comment: I am adding my javascript to the bottom of my page body on a site builder and have so far been able to test logging a parent variable and then a child variable when I delay the function until after the termly app finishes rendering it's cookies banner. I haven't seen the style change take place yet but I've tried appending the cssText and setting the specific style

Comment: `<script>
console.log("Script Firing");

const changePadding = () => {
  const parentContainer = document.querySelector('#termly-code-snippet-support');
  const banner = parentContainer.querySelectorAll('div');
  console.log(banner);
  )
};

setTimeout(changePadding, 1000);
</script>  
`

Comment: `async function functionName() {/*code what you want to execute*/}`

Comment: What is the third party script that is doing things on your page? Does it have an API?

Comment: "*I'm trying to make css changes to my termly cookie banner*" - then don't use JS and just write a CSS stylesheet. It will always apply to the matched elements, and not care about when they are rendered.

Comment: Bergi, I started with trying to edit the css file but the element doesn't change based on my css file targeting it's classes, even when using the !important notation. My thinking was that the elements are rendered with inline styling of higher specificity.